# SelectKBest not producing the appropriate results

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to do feature selection for my dataset. It contains only numerical and categorical variables after removing the unwanted variables. Code is below.

```
selector = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=5)
selector.fit(X, Y)
```

But I get very wierd output with exponential values - what could be the reason:
`print(selector[:5])`

[[2.600e+05 3.900e+01 2.500e+05 4.150e+02]

[2.060e+05 5.700e+01 1.030e+05 4.051e+02]

[2.500e+05 3.300e+01 2.500e+05 4.400e+02]

[7.500e+05 5.900e+01 7.500e+05 3.871e+03]

[5.000e+05 2.900e+01 5.000e+05 2.600e+02]]

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you pass number which is greater than 8 characters,exponential notation is imposed. Since all the values are greater than 8 characters, its displaying in exponential notation. However if you want to display entire number then you have to specify it in set_printoptions.

Comment: But my input data doesnt have such huge values. Is it working as expected?

Comment: But the values you displayed shows that they are huge numbers.

Comment: That's why I am confused if there is something wrong.

Comment: That cant be said without knowing the data.